# Widget minHeight 40dp gives 2 cells of height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Widget minHeight 40dp gives 2 cells of height during choosing a minimum height I chose 1 cells and in widget-info.xml file it is 40dp. But widget have 2 cells height after adding. When I change height (after hold down this widget), it back to 2 cells height

Comment: Please try to be more specific. Which layout are you using? Can you provide the code in order to reproduce the error!

Comment: Please clarify your question or provide some code snippets.